# How to set client information without WSConnection

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere

Our project uses Websphere, and we have to set the "client information" using [WSConnection](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/rsadapter/WSConnection.html).  The DB2 database uses these for auditing.  And that works fine in Websphere.  However, we want to use the same codebase now in a console app running outside websphere.  So I want to change the below code to be agnostic about websphere or not.

Is there some more standard way to accomplish the below?  Something using straight jdbc?  Or some other approach that let's me not create a dependency from this code to websphere and it's libraries?

```
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty(WSConnection.CLIENT_ID, userid);
            props.setProperty(WSConnection.CLIENT_APPLICATION_NAME, bpcode);

            if (connection instanceof WSConnection) {
                WSConnection wconn = (WSConnection) connection;
                wconn.setClientInformation(props);
            } else {
                log.error("Connection was NOT an instance of WSConnection so client ID and app could not be set");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, standard interfaces have been added in JDBC for setting client info.

You can set each property individually using [connection.setClientInfo(name, value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-),

Or, you can set it all at once via [connection.setClientInfo(properties)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setClientInfo-java.util.Properties-)

To determine the exact set of client info property names that your driver supports, use the [databaseMetaData.getClientInfoProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getClientInfoProperties--) method.

Comment: I also found that DB2 supports a stored procedure for it.  CALL SYSPROC.WLM_SET_CLIENT_INFO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)